# When finding the shortest route of an undirected graph with Dijkstra's algorithm, what happens to an offshoot to a vertex v that has no other edges?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I was wondering what would happen if there were a cyclic graph such as this undirected weighted one :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcPBH.png)

So as far as I am aware if 1 were the starting node, it would go to vertex 4 and then vertex 6 (with the cost of 4), since it is the shortest path. But how would it get back?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "get back"? Dijkstra's algorithm does not "go to" a vertex; it builds a tree of shortest paths.

Comment: Please make your diagram visible on here. I'm not clicking a link from a new user and I don't recommend anyone else do so either!